# Problem in Putnum competition?

Tags: functional-equations

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and $f(2x^2 -1)=2xf(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

> Prove $f(x)=0\,\,\text{for all} \, x\in [-1,1].$

Comment: @r9m, was there a change of variable $x = \cos t?$

Comment: @abel yes that's right :-)

Comment: @r9m, i still don't know how to proceed but that $2x^2 - 1$ is shouting for a double angle formula.

Comment: @abel for $t \neq n\pi$, defined $g(t) = \frac{f(\cos t)}{\sin t}$, then $g$ has period $\pi$ and $g(2t) = g(t)$, so $g(1+\frac{k\pi}{2^n}) = g(1)$ for $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$. $\{1+\frac{k\pi}{2^n} |k,n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is dense in the domain, hence $g$ is constant (by continuity)

Comment: @r9m, thanks. you ought to copy your comment as an answer.

Comment: [Putnam 2000 problem B4 solution](http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2000s.pdf)

Comment: See also: [Prove $f(x)=0$ when $f(2x^2-1)= f(x)\cdot 2x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1539373).